What does the word "Observable" mean in Quantum Gravity?
I have seen the statement in several places that the only "observables" in general relativity or Quantum Gravity are measured at temporal or spatial infinity. This is often used as a rationale/heuristic for explaining holography, or the AdS/CFT correspondence. I understand that certain quantities may not make sense locally in General Relativity e.g. we may not have time translation invariance and, as such, there is no notion of "energy" except globally for asymptotically flat spacetimes. However, I do not understand how this extends to all "observables".
I think my lack of understanding may stem from not knowing what is meant by the word "observable". I think I know what it means for a quantity to be an "observable" in Quantum Mechanics/ Quantum Field Theory. In my understanding, it means something you can actually observe or measure. For example, time-ordered correlation functions in quantum field theory (or perhaps more technically the square of correlation functions). You can, in principle, measure the field at many different space-time points and see how the measurements are correlated.
However, if I extend this notion to some theory of quantum gravity, and then say that the observables must be located at temporal or spatial infinity this appears (to me) to be a conundrum. We can never actually observe spatial or temporal infinity. All experiments are localized within some region of space thus we are never actually observing "observables". It also seems to me that quantities at spatial or temporal infinity are necessarily unobservable (in the practical sense). This would seem to me to be rather paradoxical and spell the doom of science
This seems very qualitatively different to me than the situation in quantum mechanics. There, for example, the wave function of a particle is not an observable but its square, the probability distribution of the particle, is. I interpret this as saying that the wave function is just an artifact of the larger mathematical formalism, which at the end of the day takes in a real number and spits out a real number.
I would say that science is about making a finite number of observations and then using them to predict other observations. The statement that quantum gravity does not allow any local observable seems to be at direct odds with this idea. Pardon me for being dramatic, but this seems like it would spell the doom of science.
I think perhaps my difficulty lies in understanding what is meant by an "observable" in quantum gravity.

Observables are locally conserved quantities like energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. In quantum mechanics these quantities come in form of quanta and we can only predict the average frequencies and correlations of these quanta. The problem in general relativity is that we are losing the "locally conserved" quality of the world. It doesn't mean that we can't do useful observations (we are, after all, measuring the CMB across the entire visible universe and GW from neutron star/BH mergers), they just don't have the same meaning as they had in a naive Galilean spacetime scenario.

If you think about the consequences of gravity on quantum processes, then at least naively you would expect to observe additional energy/momentum/angular momentum loss in form of gravitons. For the most part that will probably look similar to neutrinos in high energy physics processes. They are also invisible in our detectors and we therefor have to reconstruct the kinematics of the reaction under the assumption that we lost some of the outgoing energy and momentum. I am not sure that's nearly halfway as difficult and/or exciting as it sounds.

You have to be careful with what you call "quantum gravity". Is it super-string theory, loop quantum gravity, non-commutative geometry, the asymptotic safety approach, etc? What you call observable depends on the model. What @FlatterMann describes in the second comment is essentially the effective field theory approach to quantum gravity.

I think that things like integrations of fields over closed surfaces can also be viewed as observables, so it's not like you need literal asymptotic infinity to talk about an observation. On the other hand, sometimes even asymptotic observables aren't enough -- like the S-matrix is not an observable in de Sitter space. I'm not an expert in quantum gravity, but my understanding is that people know what properties an observable should have... like, gauge invariant, hermitian... but there isn't agreement on precisely what the best observables are.

@JeanbaptisteRoux I was trying to get at the question from a phenomenological point of view. Quantum gravity, as a theory, does not change the phenomenology at low energies in the least. At intermediate energies I would expect a loss of hermiticity because gravitons are escaping detection and so energy and momentum are "leaking" from our observed quantities. The question "What does a physicist at 26 Infinity Way, Singularity City, Sagittarius A* observe?" is, IMHO, unanswerable in a scientific framework.

The notions of "observables" goes back to Heisenberg's idea of formulating the laws of physics entirely based on observable quantities.

"Im Übrigen sei es doch vernünftig, in eine Theorie nur beobachtbare Größen aufzunehmen".

My translation:

Furthermore, it seems reasonable only to include quantities into the theory which are observable.

This was pretty much against the ideas of Einstein:

"Aber Sie glauben doch nicht im Ernst, dass man in eine
physikalische Theorie nur beobachtbare Größen aufnehmen kann?"

My translation:

You cannot seriosly believe, that a physical theory could only include quantieties that are observable?

The difference between "observables" and beables (i.e., things that exist in the world), is that observables only have an operational meaning, as they refer to possible observations. The word "observable" can create a lot of confusion in quantum theory as it suggest, that during an experiment the value of the observable is revealed. This is however not the case, the values are not revealed by experiments but produced (e.g., in a Stern-Gerlach experiment). More on this can be found here.
Now in the case of general relativity we have the situation that the laws of physics are invariant under diffeomorphism.

For a physical description in terms of beables this is not that much of an issue. The physical content of the solutions can be identified with the equivalence classes under diffeomorphism. The fact that a field value $\phi(x)$ of a physical field is not invariant under diffeomorphism is not a problem because it has now operational value. If the physical contant of the theory includes entities like humans, then the "observations" made by them would not be affected by diffeomorphism transformation since the transformation would not only affect the field $\phi(x)$ but also the human inhabitant. E.g., if we measure the angle between two peaks of $\phi(x)$ the result is not affected diffeomorphism transformation, because the transformation would also deform our retina and the path of the light rays.
For an operational description in terms of observables the situation is different, since the observer is not itself part of the physical description. E.g., the values of a field $\phi(x)$ do not form a valid basis for operational statements, since the values are affected by diffeomorphism. Following the idea of Heisenberg that physics should be based on "observables" a lot of work has been spent on finding the right observables for GR. E.g., one could consider the holonomy group $\operatorname{Hol}_\nabla$ as a possible observable.

String theory is an $S$-matrix theory. I.e., the things which count as observables are only the asymptotic scattering processes. The idea of $S$-matrix theory also goes back to Heisenberg. If one restricts the group of diffeomorphism to those transformations which die off at infinity, this allows for the definition of an $S$-matrix that is invariant under diffeomorphism.
You are absolutely right in stating that

that quantities at spatial or temporal infinity are necessarily unobservable
Insofar as you mean quantities that are beables (e.g, everything that existed at the start of the big bang). However, observables at infinity only have an operational meaning. For example, in string theory they have the meaning of events you would observe if you build a collider of the sice of our solar system (or maybe larger). In the operational setting, the detectors are thought of being located at asymptotic infinity. This idealization works for all practical purpose (it already used in usual quantum field theory).

But if you are interested in the question of what happens in-between (which not all physicist are) there is a drawback to the operational approach. This was already pointed out by John Steward Bell:

``Well again they have over sold their message to the general public, I would say. When you press them, you find that whereas they are announcing a theory of everything, they only have theories of S matrix elements. That's to say, bodies come in from infinity, and they say nothing until they go out again at infinity. But we don't refer to infinity. And in order to make a serious theory, including gravity, it must not be an S-matrix theory but a field theory, which discusses things at finite times and places. And they can't do it. They have tried very hard and given up.''

Of course there are views diverging from John Bell.
